# Difference between yamero and yamete

Tags: word-choice, usage, rōmaji

I often hear this from animations and read it among users when making jokes on the internet, but I wonder exactly: what's the difference between yamero and yamete?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of the two **やめろ (yamero)** is the bossier one.  **やめて (yamete)** comes across a bit softer; it's basically **やめてください (yamete kudasai)** minus the ください (kudasai).  **やめろ (yamero)** is actually the imperative form of the verb, hence the pushy sense it can give off.

**やめて (yamete)** sounds like something a girl might say, but certainly isn't restricted to girls; 　**やめろ (yamero)** sounds like something either guys would say to each other, or someone (anyone) might say to someone who's really not getting the idea that they need to stop.

Comment: I wouldn't say やめて sounds feminine, just softer. I've heard plenty of guys say it.

Comment: Sorry, can you transcribe them in romaji too?

Comment: @Fabián i've add romaji and incorporated kurausukun's comment

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to add やめなさい, just in case? I'm not sure how further you can answer since he was specific about 　やめて、やめろ